# White flash appears in Chrome when loading a dead simple Google Maps "Hello, World" page

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I see a white flash in Google Chrome when I load the following very basic "Hello, World" program:

http://mobdealio.com/124

It's a single index.html file.

The white flash only appears when the page is loaded in a brand new Chrome tab or window. If you reload the page a second time in the same tab or window, the problem flash doesn't appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This should be a comment, but I can't add a comment at my current level on StackOverflow.*

It seems that this is a recent bug with Google Chrome. I'm getting the same behavior using Chrome on Win7. I can stop the behavior from happening by disabling the adding of markers to my map in my code. Simply commenting out

```
new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(e.lat, e.lng),
    map: map
});
```

"Fixes" my issue (white flash goes away). Unfortunately I can't do this because I need my map to display markers!

The issue doesn't occur after the page content is already cached, and doesn't occur in Firefox at all.

Comment: This was a bug in Chrome on Windows 7, confirmed by a Google employee. But it seems the bug is fixed...my (auto-updating) Chrome no longer does it.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably seeing a "flash", because the files (html and js) haven't been cached yet. When you reload your page, the page is retrieved from the cache, hence no "flash".

I don't see a flash when visiting your site, because I've got a fast internet connection, and an empty cache, in a live session in RAM (Linux).

Comment: @Sanjay Your page loads, and gets drawed (no content, #1). Then, the scripts have finished loading too, and the page is redrawed (#2). The flash you're seeing is the transition from no content (#1) to #2.

Comment: I appreciate your help and time, Rob. But I've simplified the code even further here: http://mobdealio.com/125/  If you press the link, all that happens is setMap(map) is called on a marker. The flash still happens (in a new Chrome tab).

Comment: Here it is as a jsfiddle. Again, it only happens the first time in a new Chrome tab. http://jsfiddle.net/QLbYD/

Comment: I've also tested some other sites, including http://maps.google.com The "flash" seems to occur everywhere. The flash is purely visual, and caused by the contrast update (blank > map content). At your original page, I hardly notice any flash. What browser version are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome 15.0.874.106 m on Windows 7. The flash only appears on the _first_ load of the page in a new tab. I think I'm going to write this off as a Chrome or Google Maps bug...does that sound right to you?

Comment: Visit an arbitrary page with (multiple) images and press `CTRL+F5`. By this method, I am able to get a flash at almost every page I want to visit. I don't think that it's a bug. Add some text to the top of your page. If the map flashes, but the text doesn't, my notice is proven.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing some webdevelopment, and i had the same thing happening on my own site.
After milions of error checking i finaly got these flashes.

This is javascript related, and is a design flaw, i moved part of my javascript from the header to the functions.php, right after the css style, this fixed the problem for now, ive try'd everything it did not work.

It also could be a Chrome bug, i am checking my site over and over again, for mistakes.
For weeks now, never have i seen these flashes untill last night.

But it is fixed and i am happy so..
Good luck.